# 0x API not using slippage for orders that only provide a buyAmount

Tags: 0x, swaps

**Does the 0x API correctly determine a `sellAmount` when given a `buyAmount` and a specific `slippage`?**

In the [documentation](https://docs.0x.org/0x-api-swap/api-references/get-swap-v1-quote) is says the following about the slippage parameter

> (Optional) The maximum acceptable slippage of the buyToken amount if sellAmount is provided; The maximum acceptable slippage of the sellAmount amount if buyAmount is provided. E.g 0.03 for 3% slippage allowed.

But both of these `/swap/v1/quote` requests produce the same `takerAmount` even with very different slippage.

**slippage set to `0.1`**

```
{
  "buyToken": "0xfa5047c9c78b8877af97bdcb85db743fd7313d4a",
  "sellToken": "0x7ff4169a6b5122b664c51c95727d87750ec07c84",
  "slippagePercentage": 0.1,
  "skipValidation": "true",
  "intentOnFilling": "true",
  "buyAmount": 1000000000000000000000
}
```

**slippage set to `0.5`**

```
{
  "buyToken": "0xfa5047c9c78b8877af97bdcb85db743fd7313d4a",
  "sellToken": "0x7ff4169a6b5122b664c51c95727d87750ec07c84",
  "slippagePercentage": 0.5,
  "skipValidation": "true",
  "intentOnFilling": "true",
  "buyAmount": 1000000000000000000000
}
```

**API response**

```
{
  "makerToken": "0xfa5047c9c78b8877af97bdcb85db743fd7313d4a",
  "takerToken": "0x7ff4169a6b5122b664c51c95727d87750ec07c84",
  "makerAmount": "1000000000000000000000",
  "takerAmount": "41002212925764457213198",
  "fillData": {
    "tokenAddressPath": [
      "0x7ff4169a6b5122b664c51c95727d87750ec07c84",
      "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2",
      "0xfa5047c9c78b8877af97bdcb85db743fd7313d4a"
    ],
    "router": "0xf164fc0ec4e93095b804a4795bbe1e041497b92a"
  },
  "source": "Uniswap_V2",
  "sourcePathId": "0x1cf4a7984db8f5cc1ec4dccfeae82934796000f1cc836d50a0bdbd86ec264f5e",
  "type": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `orders` field in the response is mostly informational. They're not even fillable anywhere. The `data` field should have the actual sell amount adjusted for slippage (`takerAmount`) encoded as part of the calldata.

Comment: so where in the API response can I see the amount that is going into the trade? 
as set by slippage?